# Ignoring html tags in regexp

Tags: javascript, css, regex

here's my code

```
replaced.replace(new RegExp(item, 'i'), "<span class='has-background-primary'>$&</span>");
```

it's highlighting searched term. But if I run it second time and serach for eg. "back", it will do stupid things like replacing string in the tag class. What can I do to prevent it?

Comment: Trim the tags from the string first. [By using this answer for example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/822486/743016).

Comment: but can I recreate the trimmed tags then? I need both

Comment: You could use a parser... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Is my solution working?

Answer (score 0):

The "literal" solution is to match the tag you want to skip and then match a keyword in any other context, and, upon a match, check if your term or the tag was matched, and replace accordingly:

```
var regex = new RegExp("(<span class='has-background-primary'>[^]*?</span>)|"+item.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&'), 'gi');
var result = replaced.replace(regex, function ($0, $1) {
    return $1 ? $0 : "<span class='has-background-primary'>" + $0 + "</span>";
});
```

Say, your item is `house`. So, the regex will look like `/(<span class='has-background-primary'>[^]*?</span>)|house/gi`. It will match and capture `<span class='has-background-primary'>`, 0+ chars as few as possible (with `[^]*?`) and then `</span>`, else, the key word is matched. If Group 1 matched, the match is pasted back as is, else, it is wrapped with new `span` tags.

Note that it is advised to [escape your literal strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript) to be used as RegExp patterns, hence, `.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')` is added.

Another idea is to build a pattern from the search terms dynamically, like

```js
var search = ['abc', 'abcde', 'xyz'];
search.sort(function(a, b){
  return b.length - a.length;
});
var rx = new RegExp(search.map(function(m) { 
    return m.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');}
  ).join("|"), "gi"); // => /abcde|abc|xyz/gi
var result = replaced.replace(rx, "<span class='has-background-primary'>$&</span>"));
```

Since your alternation group is unanchored and a search word may represent a subset of another term, you should sort the search words by length in the descending order.

Then, build the alternation while escaping each value, do not forget the `g` modifier here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if what you're looking for is somewhere along the lines of the following modified code:
replaced.replace(new RegExp(item, 'i'), "$&".indexOf(">"));

This should ensure the html tag is not impacted